# Trying to pass arguments using PathVariable results in Error Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.lang.Long'

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm building this simple application for my parents to have an easier "check list" of what bills have been paid. I've taken it upon myself to build it (free of charge, duh), as a mean of practice and a real workflow role play. Everything went smoothly, except few minor errors, but this time I've been stuck for a few days and just can't wrap my head around this problem...

I try passing arguments using @PathVariable, to setup some default values such as type and city. Everything else is modifiable and should not have a default value. Now, I've created 3 cards, each representing it's own city with a dropdown to select what type of bill you would like to save, write in, whatever you call it. Now, every `<li>` in the dropdown is a type. A type is the name of the bill, such as: water, internet, garbage collection etc. Standard stuff...Now my idea was to have each of the `<li>` be clickable and so that when you click on it, you would be redirected to a page that has already populated the type and city for you, and you only have to fill in the rest, such as price and description.

I'm using Java Spring Boot and Thymeleaf (I didn't want to bother using something else other than Thymeleaf because I wanted to try and learn it just a bit).

Here is the code in question:

controller:

```
@GetMapping("/racuni")
    public String getRacuniTemplate(Model model){
        return racunService.getTemplates(model);
    }

@GetMapping("/racun/new/{type}/{city}")
    public String createRacunForm(Model model, @PathVariable String type, @PathVariable String city) {
        return racunService.createRacunForm(model, type, city);
    }

@PostMapping("/racun/new")
    public String createRacun(@ModelAttribute racun racun){
        return racunService.createNewRacun(racun);
    }
```

Service:

```
public String getTemplates(Model model){
        racun racunZagreb = new racun();
        racun racunSplit = new racun();
        racun racunRijeka = new racun();

        model.addAttribute("racunZagreb", racunZagreb);
        model.addAttribute("racunSplit", racunSplit);
        model.addAttribute("racunRijeka", racunRijeka);

        return "racuni-template";
    }

public String createRacunForm(Model model, String type, String city){
        racun racun = new racun();
        racun.setType(type);
        racun.setCity(city);

        model.addAttribute("racun", racun);
        return "racun_new";
    }

public String createNewRacun(racun racun){
        racunRepository.save(racun);

        return "redirect:/racun/" + racun.getId();
    }
```

Thymeleaf template:

```
<div>
  <div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-md-3 g-4">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Rijeka</h5>
          <p class="card-text">Ovdje možeš odabrati račune za Rijeku</p>
          <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
              <a th:href="@{/racun/new(type='Čistoća', city='Rijeka')}">Čistoća</a>
              <a th:href="@{/racun/new(type='Komunalije', city='Rijeka')}">Komunalije</a>
              <a th:href="@{/racun/new(type='Voda', city='Rijeka')}">Voda</a>
              <a th:href="@{/racun/new(type='Internet', city='Rijeka')}">Internet</a>
              <a th:href="@{/racun/new(type='Struja', city='Rijeka')}">Struja</a>
              <a th:href="@{/racun/new(type='Ostalo', city='Rijeka')}">Ostalo</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Zagreb</h5>
          <p class="card-text">Ovdje možeš odabrati račune za Zagreb</p>
          <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
              <a th:href="@{/racun/new(type='Čistoća', city='Zagreb')}">Čistoća</a>
              <a th:href="@{/racun/new(type='Komunalije', city='Zagreb')}">Komunalije</a>
              <a th:href="@{/racun/new(type='Voda', city='Zagreb')}">Voda</a>
              <a th:href="@{/racun/new(type='Internet', city='Zagreb')}">Internet</a>
              <a th:href="@{/racun/new(type='Struja', city='Zagreb')}">Struja</a>
              <a th:href="@{/racun/new(type='Ostalo', city='Zagreb')}">Ostalo</a>
              <a th:href="@{/racun/new(type='Maximus', city='Zagreb')}">Maximus</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Split</h5>
          <p class="card-text">Ovdje možeš odabrati račune za Split</p>
          <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
              <a th:href="@{/racun/new(type='Čistoća', city='Split')}">Čistoća</a>
              <a th:href="@{/racun/new(type='Komunalije', city='Split')}">Komunalije</a>
              <a th:href="@{/racun/new(type='Voda', city='Split')}">Voda</a>
              <a th:href="@{/racun/new(type='Internet', city='Split')}">Internet</a>
              <a th:href="@{/racun/new(type='Struja', city='Split')}">Struja</a>
              <a th:href="@{/racun/new(type='Ostalo', city='Split')}">Ostalo</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Once I run this and try to acces any of the dropdown items, I get hit with this error:

There was an unexpected error (type=Bad Request, status=400).
Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.lang.Long'; For input string: "new"
org.springframework.web.method.annotation.MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.lang.Long'; For input string: "new"

I don't know why it insists there should be a required type "long" when I pass in String and expect a String. The only thing that comes to my mind is an ID, but I haven't exposed IDs, so yea...IDK... Please help, I'd really really appreciate it. Thanks in advance

EDIT: The template is "racuni-template.html"

Comment: Please add the full stacktrace and the error isn't related to the methods you shown here. There appears to be a method like `@GetMapping("/racun/{id}")` which is being called. The `@{/racun/new(type='Čistoća', city='Rijeka')}` doesn't do what you think it does, there is no `type` nor `city` placeholder in your URL template, so it doesn't do anything. SHould be something like `@{/racun/new/{type}/{city}(type='Čistoća', city='Rijeka')}` else it would generate parameters not path variables.

Comment: @M.Deinum Yes, you are right. The @{/racun/new/{type}/{city}(type='Čistoća', city='Rijeka')} worked as intented. Thank you so much...BTW The @GetMapping("/racun/{id}") is for calling all the bills (racuni). The "racuni-template"... Thanks for your help tho :)

Answer (score 1):

The error was in HTML:
I wrote @{/racun/new(type='Čistoća', city='Rijeka')} but the correct way was @{/racun/new/{type}/{city}(type='Čistoća', city='Rijeka')}

Credit: M.Deinum

Thanks to M.Deinum